# How to modify the label of Category Field in amCharts

Tags: angularjs, amcharts, ammap

I am using amCharts in my AngularJS application and I am looking for a way to rename the label of the category field. Following is my code:

```
var configChart = function () {
            employeeChart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            employeeChart.categoryField = "empId";

            var yAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            yAxis.position = "left";
            employeeChart.addValueAxis(yAxis);

            mcfBarGraph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            mcfBarGraph.valueField = "employeeRating";
            mcfBarGraph.type = "column";
            mcfBarGraph.fillAlphas = 1;
            mcfBarGraph.lineColor = "#f0ab00";
            mcfBarGraph.valueAxis = yAxis;
            employeeChart.addGraph(empBarGraph);

            employeeChart.write('employee');


        }
```

In the above coode if you observe the categoryField is empId so on the x-axis it shows employee Id's, I want to make it "dept-empId". For example if the department number is 1, on the x-axis it show display 1-1,1-2 etc. The department Id is not in the data provider but is one of the scope variables in my controller. Could you let me know how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [labelFunction](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#labelFunction) in your chart object's categoryAxis to get the formatting you want.

```
var categoryAxis = employeeChart.categoryAxis;
categoryAxis.labelFunction = function(valueText) {
  return dept + '-' + valueText;
};
```

Here's a fiddle that uses your setup with some dummy data to illustrate this: https://jsfiddle.net/by7grqjm/2/

Comment: Thanks for your help.But initially when the page loads it is giving me the value as undefined and once I refresh the chart again the value appears. The value is being returned from a service in AngularJs and I am assigning this value to a variable and using it in the way u suggested. I tried printing the value using console.log and the value is undefined. So can you let me know why it is undefined until I refresh the chart.

Comment: If you can provide a fiddle that reproduces your scenario I can take a closer look.

Comment: I understood what is causing it. The service that is returning the dept Id is an $http service so it is getting called last in the controller and the code for the charts is executed before this. So is there a way to get this value before the charts code is executed.

Comment: Well it's asynchronous, so you have to figure out a way to either make the chart render after your http call possibly by using a promise, which may or may not be a clean way of doing it, or have your service tell the chart to redraw itself by calling the chart object's validateNow method after the value is populated.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on the second part that you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: However your services/controllers/etc are set up in your angular app, you need to architect a way to have that service tell your chart that the http request returned a value to the deptId. Consider looking into `$broadcast` or `$emit` and have the controller that created the chart listen to your event through `$scope.on` and call validateNow on the `employeeChart` object. Check the angular docs, tutorials and even the numerous examples on SO on how to work with events.